# Query With Join

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm working with C# MVC3 and Entity Framework.
I have a table that contains 2 FK's.
So, I want to execute this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1 f,
       TABLE2       r,
       TABLE3       c
 WHERE f.codx = r.codx
   AND f.cody = c.cody
```

TABLE1 = Contains FK's

So, I need to Include at his DbSet a reference the tables....
But, How can I add two tables at my DbSet?
The problem that I receive this DbSet from another class, and add in my query:

```
return ((from table1 in this.GetContext<Fake>().TABLE1.Include("TABLE2") //Here I need to Include another table, was working with just one
        where (
      ............. )
        select).ToList<Table1>());
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `.Include` methods together:

```
return ((from table1 in this.GetContext<Fake>().TABLE1.Include("TABLE2").Include("TABLE3")
        where (
      ............. )
        select).ToList<Table1>());
```

Comment: But, I'll not Include Table3 ON table2?

Comment: The order is not relevant.  All the mappings are known through the model.